# JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be a string, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, backend, verify

I'm getting the error **JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be a string** when getting the jwt from the front end (react.js) and using in middleware to verify the token. If I tried to use toString it gives me another error **JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed**.

**Update**

As soon as i pass the accessToken from frontEnd it converted into object in the AuthMiddleware.js. I'm passing middleware on header in file Post.js(attached below)

**AuthMiddleware.js**

```
const { verify } = require("jsonwebtoken")


const validateToken = (res, req, next) => {
    const accesToken = req.header("accesToken");
    const stringAccesToken = accesToken.toString()
    console.log(typeof (stringAccesToken), "accesToken type")

if (!stringAccesToken) {
    return res.json({ error: "user not logged in" })

}

try {
    const validToken = verify(stringAccesToken, "importantSecret");
    console.log(validToken, 'validtoken')
    if (validToken) {
        return next();
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err, "error")
    }

}

module.exports = { validateToken }
```

**User.js (backend for login)**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router()
const { Users } = require("../models")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")

const { sign } = require("jsonwebtoken")

  

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { username: username } });

    if (!user) {
        return res.json({ error: "User dosen't exist" })
    }

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        .then((match) => {
            if (!match) {
                return res.json({ error: "Wrong Username and Password match" })
            }
            const accessToken = sign({ username: user.username, id: user.id }, "importantSecret")
            res.json(accessToken)
        })
})

module.exports = router;
```

**Post.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Post.css'


function Post() {

    let { id } = useParams();

    const [postObject, setPostObject] = useState({})
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
    const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState("");

    // console.log(comments)

    const addComment = () => {


        const accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')
        console.log(typeof (accessToken), 'acces token in comment button')

        axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/comments`,
            {
                commentBody: newComment,
                PostId: id
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    accessToken: sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken"),
                }
            }
        )
            .then((res) => {
                // console.log(res)
                const data = res.data;
                console.log(data, 'comments')

                setComments([...comments, data])
                setNewComment("")
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                alert(err, 'Error:comment')
            })
    }



    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/posts/byId/${id}`)
            .then((res) => {
                // console.log(res)
                const data = res.data;
                // console.log(data)

                setPostObject(data)
                // setPost(data)

            })

        // comment api request
        axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/comments/${id}`)
            .then((res) => {
                // console.log(res)
                const data = res.data;
                // console.log(data)

                setComments(data)

            })
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className='Post'>

            <div className='left__side'>
                <div className='left__side__wrapper'>

                    <div className='title'>{postObject.title}</div>
                    <div className='text'>{postObject.postText}</div>
                    <div className='username'>{postObject.username}</div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div className='right__side'>
                <div className='right__side__wrapper'>
                    <div className='add__comment__container'>

                        <input type="text"
                            value={newComment}
                            placeholder="Comment"
                            //  autoComplete="off"
                            onChange={(e) => setNewComment(e.target.value)}

                        />
                        <button onClick={addComment}> Submit Comment</button>

                    </div>
                    <div className='listOfCommnets'>

                        {comments.map((item, index) => {
                            {/* console.log(item, 'item') */ }
                            return <div className='comments' key={index}>Comments:<br />{item.commentBody}</div>

                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Post
```

Comment: did you chnge the secret or something. you can check and validate the token from https://jwt.io/

Comment: Is this a typo? Should `accesToken` be `accessToken`? Also, HTTP headers are usually kebab-cased, ie. `Access-Token`. Does that help?

Comment: How are you adding the token on the client?

Comment: @coagmano It's not a type i user everywhere as accesToken. Im using session storage to add it like this ( sessionStorage.setItem("accesToken", result.data.accesToken))

Comment: Once it's in `sessionStorage`, how are you adding it to requests to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Because the jwt token is using an object as an input rather than using the word "verify," it won't work with the object in which you are receiving the error any longer. Instead, you must attempt as follows.

```
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const validateToken = (res, req, next) => {
const accesToken = req.header("accesToken");
const stringAccesToken = accesToken;

if (!stringAccesToken) {
   return res.json({ error: "user not logged in" });
}

jwt.verify(stringAccesToken, "importantSecret", function (err, decoded) {
  if (err)
    return console.log(err)
  // Next Code
  next();
 });
};

module.exports = { validateToken };
```

Comment: While it might be different in your situation, you can still try because it worked for me.

Comment: No that's not it, `jsonwebtoken`'s verify method doesn't use `this` so won't care if you import `jwt` or destructure `verify`. See [source](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/verify.js)

Comment: @TechnoDeveloper I tried but it's giving the same error (jwt must be string)

Comment: Can you tell me about setting up your JWT token, @SharanjeetSingh? There might be an error or anything.

Comment: @TechnoDeveloper sure, i just added the file (User.js) where i'm setting up the jwt.

Comment: Also i changet the name accesToken to accessToken in every file

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
As the error said JWT need to be string,

I first tried using accesToken.toString() that gives [object object],
On second try i used JSON.stringy and that was also unsuccessful.

Final scuccesful attemp was to use library name - flatted (to convert json to string and after using it i just used split till i did'nt get the token).

faltted (link) - https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted

**Worked Solution -**

**AuthMiddleware.js**

```
const { parse, stringify, toJSON, fromJSON } = require('flatted');



const validateToken = (res, req, next) => {


    const authToken = req.header("accessToken");
    const string = stringify(authToken)
    const token = string && string.split(' ')[2];
    const tokenPure = token.split('"')[4]

    if (!tokenPure) {
        return res.json({ error: "user not logged in" })

    }
    try {
        const validToken = verify(tokenPure, "importantSecret");
        // console.log(validToken, 'validtoken')
        if (validToken) {
            return next();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err, "error")
    }

}

module.exports = { validateToken }
```